# Redirection to standard output in VBS

Tags: vbscript

When writing a script in **sh** or in **cmd** you can put a *>* at the end of a line to have the output of that line redirected to a file. If not, it is sent to the standard output.

Also, both have the **echo** command to produce output to the standard output (which can, in turn, be redirected too).

How to perform those two things in a VBS script?

Comment: I have searched through the solutions already in SO and they have not worked for me (or I have not been able to make them work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing different. You only need to make sure your scripts are run with the console based script host **cscript**.

myscript.vbs:

```
' WScript.Echo is a host-aware hybrid method. 
' in cscript, prints the message with final a new line feed, also accepts vary arguments (0 or more).
' in wscript, shows a message dialog window
WScript.Echo "test1", "arg2"

' WScript.Stdout.Write on the other hand is a more traditional way to write to standard output stream
' print the message as is with no new line feeds
WScript.Stdout.Write "test"
WScript.Stdout.Write "2"
```

Command:

```
cscript myscript.vbs
```

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

test1 arg2
test2
```

There's also an option to prevent to display banner on the output.

```
cscript //NoLogo myscript.vbs
```

Output:

```
test1 arg2
test2
```

Redirection:

```
cscript //NoLogo myscript.vbs>output.txt
```

---

PS: cscript is the default script interpreter only on Windows Server operating systems. Otherwise the default is wscript. Therefore it is a good practice to run the scripts with a specific script host.

To change the default script host have a look at [Running Your Scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b(v=vs.84).aspx)

**Useful Links:**

---

- [Echo Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f603s7(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [Write Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5wwy2xet(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [Running Your Scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I need not to use cscript because I need to launch Excel from the VBS, but the answer is exactly what I asked for.