# How to return an ArrayList in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to return an ArrayList from a function in VBScript. The code goes through mails and extracts the Subject and Sender from them and stores them into An ArrayList. Then I Set the ArrayList to the name of the function to return it.
But no returns are being output as arguments.

I execute the VBScript through CMD and only shows

C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents>cscript DetailSaver.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Function getDetails()

    Set outlook = createobject("outlook.application")
    Set session = outlook.getnamespace("mapi")
    session.logon

    Set inbox = session.getdefaultfolder(6).Folders("Clasification")
    Set newFolder = inbox.Folders("Devs")
    Set detailList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim emailSubject
    Dim emailSender
    Dim emailObject

    For Each m In newFolder.items
        If m.unread  Then 

            emailSubject = m.Subject
            emailSender = m.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
            emailObject = emailSender & "|.|" & emailSubject
            detailList.Add emailObject

            m.Unread = False
        End If
    Next

    session.logoff

    Set outlook = Nothing
    Set CaseTitle = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
    'Set detailList = Nothing

    Set getDetails = detailList

End Function

Call getDetails()

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: When run, this calls the `getDetails()` function, then exits. It doesn't do anything with the returned list. What are you expecting? Also, note that using `System.Collections.ArrayList` will only work on systems with .Net 2 or 3.5 on them. It will fail on systems with just .Net 4.x (like Win10).Why not use a type that VBScript understands natively, like `Dictionary`?

Comment: Why use `System.Collections.ArrayList` at all and not VBScript's native Array?

Comment: @ArnovanBoven I am trying to output the ArrayList to use it as input argument by other software. The other software captures the output argument of the vbscript execution.
I can print in function as `wscript.echo join(detailList.ToArray(), vbCrLf)` but the Windows Script Host Window appears when executed. I was trying to return value without using echo. 
& Thanks! For sure will try `Dictionary`

Comment: @HelO'Ween Not sure why I went with `System.Collections.ArrayList` will try with VBScript native Arrays :)

Comment: @silver_lynx I am not sure you can return a value from VBScript other than an `Integer`: `WScript.Quit someExitCode`, where `someExitCode` is an `Integer`. It's been ages since I used it so I may be wrong. PowerShell can do it. Or you could perhaps write the desired output to some file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could start the third-party tool with a command parameter from the script, assuming it supports that.

Comment: @aron-von-boven: I think it can, via [WScript.StdOut.Write](https://ss64.com/vb/stdoutwrite.html). See also this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475335/redirection-to-standard-output-in-vbs).

Answer (score 0):

at the end of your script the command Call is eating up the output and sending it nowhere.
Instead of Call, use a new variable name.

```
arrData = getDetails()
```

But then did you want to output it's values?

```
For Each strArrayEntry In arrData
    'This will loop each item in the array
    Wscript.Echo strArrayEntry
Next
```